# Arduino pins not working

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm building my first arduino project and I encountered a strange problems;

I build a haunted house based upon that instructables tutorial:
https://www.instructables.com/id/Control-Your-Halloween-Decorations-With-Arduino/

Every prop works, I tried to light them on and off (it works), but when I try to use all of them, a few doesn't work.

There is my code; Is it something I'm doing wrong?

```
int propSqueDans = 4; 
int propClownImmo = 5;
int propClownJambes = 6;
int propSqueBal = 7;
int propSqueMini = 8;
int propSpider = 9; 
int propChauSou = 10;
int propFantChai = 11; 

int SensorPin = 3; // sensor connected to analog pin 3 
int SensorVal = 0; // variable to store the value read

void setup() { 
  pinMode(propSqueDans, OUTPUT);// sets the digital pin as output 
  pinMode(propClownImmo, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(propClownJambes, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(propSqueBal, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(propSqueMini, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(propChauSou, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(propFantChai, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(propSpider, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  }

void loop() { 
    SensorVal = analogRead(SensorPin); // read the input pin

    if (SensorVal >100) {
    Serial.write("Danse + Clown Immo \n"); 
    digitalWrite(propSqueDans, HIGH); 
    digitalWrite(propClownImmo, HIGH); 
    delay(10000); 
    Serial.write("Spider + Fangtôme + Clown jambes \n"); 
    digitalWrite(propSpider, HIGH); 
    digitalWrite(propFantChai, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(propClownJambes, HIGH); 

    delay(5000);
    Serial.write("Squelette balance + sque mini \n");
    digitalWrite(propSqueBal, HIGH); 
    digitalWrite(propSqueMini, HIGH); 

    delay(5000);
    Serial.write("Chauve souris \n");
    digitalWrite(propChauSou, HIGH);

    delay(20000);


    digitalWrite(propSqueDans, LOW); 
    digitalWrite(propClownJambes, LOW); 
    digitalWrite(propSqueBal, LOW); 
    digitalWrite(propSqueMini, LOW); 
    digitalWrite(propChauSou, LOW); 
    digitalWrite(propFantChai, LOW); 
    digitalWrite(propSpider, LOW); 
    digitalWrite(propClownImmo, LOW); 
    delay(5000); 
    }

  }
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Please show us your circuit (schematic). Also describe further, what is connected to the pins. Do you try to drive any motor or servo directly from the pins?

Answer (score 1):

My best guess (not knowing what the pins are driving) is that your trying to draw too much current from the Arduino gpio.

Ref: https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/ArduinoPinCurrentLimitations

Comment: Hello Andre, I guess you're right; could you tell me if a better arduino will have more current ?

Comment: Uno and Mega are pretty much the same. I would suggest using a relay module.